# Slide an image across the screen as the page loads (caching issues)

Tags: jquery, slide

I am trying to slide an image across the screen as the page loads, it works however the first time it loads the image before executing the script. The second time it works fine, i guess this is due to caching.

Does any one have a solution to my problem.
Here is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#1-slide').animate({'right':'0'},255,'linear', function(){
        console.log('Done Animation);
    });
} );
```

Comment: if you want to load script when page load use window.load

Comment: There's an error in your snippet: missing `'` after "Animation."  I hope that's just a copypasta error.

Answer (score 1):

You can, and as i believe should, preload your images using a standard preload function or plugin. here is an example:

```
$.fn.preload = function() {
    this.each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

$(['img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg']).preload();
```

This will ensure the image is loaded before-hand.

Comment: Would it be best to put this in an external script or in the head?

Comment: it is really your preference. I never put anything in the head. I keep a standard boiler plate of plugins in a file and load it after my jQuery lib. plugins.jquery.js.

Comment: here is the example http://luvly.co.nz/space/akatarawa-road.html I have included it in an external js, but still cantseem to get it to preload

Comment: First, I would recommend compressing the image http://www.imageoptimizer.net/Pages/Home.aspx. At least some. That will reduce a lot of problems. It looks like the path to your image is incorrect in the script. It should be `images/aka/aka1.jpg` not just `aka.jpg`.